# Android ScrollView Scroll to specific row

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm using TableLayout in ScrollView and my aim is scrolling to specific TableRow. For example, I have 10 TableRows and due to my query, I want the fifth row should be at top of ScrollView. scrollTo method does not work efficiently as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  you can use some like this:

```
  <ScrollView>
    <row >

   <TextView 
       android:text="@string/text1"
       /> 
       TextView 
       android:text="@string/text2"   
       />     
    </row>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Then, how can I go to TextView? There will be much TextView. By the way, I forgot to say that I'm adding rows programmatically.

Comment: the same way you are adding you're rows on a table layout, add them to a scoll view. First, you add a ScrollView to the table lay out. Finally, you add you're rows to the ScrollView.